# string.Length > 0 and string.Length != 0

Tags: c#

Is there any difference, in terms of performance, between the following c# code:

```
string s = "abc";
bool notEmpty1 = s.Length != 0;
bool notEmpty2 = s.Length > 0
```

If there is not, which is a better coding guideline? I'd also be interested to see if there are other languages that have different behaviour than c# in this example.

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)`

Comment: @Rob I considered this, but do I really need this if I know `s` will never be null?

Comment: Also you can check like this: `bool notEmpty = !s.Equals(String.Empty)`

Comment: @gsgsgs Or even *more* complex examples. Why stop at something that is still relatively readable?

Comment: At best, the first choice will be 1 CPU execution better. Not anything that would be noticed even with the wildest micro benchmarking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I've decided to test, and the results are somewhat inconclusive, but it's clear that any difference in performance is slim to none.

Here is the code I've written to test it:

```
    var times = 100000;
    string s = "abc";
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        bool notEmpty1 = s.Length != 0;
    }
    var diff = sw.Elapsed;
    sw.Restart();
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        bool notEmpty2 = s.Length > 0;
    }
    var gt = sw.Elapsed;
    sw.Restart();
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        bool notEmpty3 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
    }
    var noe = sw.Elapsed;
    sw.Restart();
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        bool notEmpty4 = s.Any();
    }
    var any = sw.Elapsed;
    sw.Restart();
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        bool notEmpty4 = s != string.Empty;
    }
    var dif2 = sw.Elapsed;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("!= {0}\n> {1}\nIsNullOrEmpty {2}\nAny {3}\n!= empty {4}", diff.TotalMilliseconds, gt.TotalMilliseconds, noe.TotalMilliseconds, any.TotalMilliseconds, dif2.TotalMilliseconds));
```

And here are some test results:

```
!= 0.4986
> 0.451
IsNullOrEmpty 0.3965
Any 6.8151
!= empty 0.5844

!= 0.7649
> 0.7822
IsNullOrEmpty 0.5672
Any 3.4259
!= empty 0.5104

!= 0.7984
> 0.5202
IsNullOrEmpty 0.3484
Any 3.3951
!= empty 0.4786

!= 0.9502
> 0.6104
IsNullOrEmpty 0.4877
Any 4.1838
!= empty 0.6849
```

You can run it yourself in [this fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MmR3UX)

Comment: Running microbenchmark in fiddler, are You serious? Here are some real results for 1M cycles: != 0,2939 ; > 0,2936 ; IsNullOrEmpty 0,587 ; Any 18,0589 ; != empty 2,3353

Comment: Actually, I wrote and tested on a new console app. I only did the fiddle to give the OP the chance to copy it to his own environment and run it directly without needing to add anything.

Comment: But It seems to me that You presented results from fiddler, not from the console app.

Comment: Yes, easier to copy.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek edited the results to results from a console app.

Answer (score 4):

Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of this:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)
```

or

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string)
```

but you can use this:

```
s.Length > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 for string.empty (cb.net equiv.)

Also, why are you checking the negative?

```
Bool isEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
```

Comment: ".. for string.empty"? What is that suppose to mean?

Comment: I was trying to say that I give a +1 vote to the guy that said to actually see if the string was empty. In van you can do string.empty(variable) rather than manually checking its length

Answer (score 0):

Using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/):

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Program
{
    public const string TestString = "foobar";

    [Benchmark]
    public bool LengthNotEqualToZero() => TestString.Length != 0;

    [Benchmark]
    public bool LengthGreaterThanZero() => TestString.Length > 0;

    [Benchmark]
    public bool IsNotNullOrEmpty() => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(TestString);

    [Benchmark]
    public bool IsNotNullEmptyOrWhitespace() => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TestString);

    [Benchmark]
    public bool Any() => TestString Any();

    [Benchmark]
    public bool IsNotEmpty() => TestString != String.Empty;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run(typeof(Program));
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

The resutls using .NET 6.0.11 w/ Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) v17.7.4:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LengthNotEqualToZero | 0.0063 ns | 0.0068 ns | 0.0064 ns | 0.0056 ns | - | - |
| LengthGreaterThanEqualZero | 0.0015 ns | 0.0023 ns | 0.0018 ns | 0.0008 ns | - | - |
| IsNotNullOrEmpty | 0.0016 ns | 0.0034 ns | 0.0030 ns | 0.0000 ns | - | - |
| IsNotNullEmptyOrWhitespace | 1.0499 ns | 0.0352 ns | 0.0329 ns | 1.0339 ns | - | - |
| Any | 17.0222 ns | 0.2055 ns | 0.1922 ns | 17.1216 ns | 0.0025 | 32 B |
| IsNotEmpty | 0.0004 ns | 0.0017 ns | 0.0016 ns | 0.0000 ns | - | - |

---

The results using .NET 7.0.11 w/ Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) v17.7.4:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LengthNotEqualToZero | 0.0007 ns | 0.0018 ns | 0.0017 ns | 0.0000 ns | - | - |
| LengthGreaterThanEqualZero | 0.0024 ns | 0.0066 ns | 0.0058 ns | 0.0000 ns | - | - |
| IsNotNullOrEmpty | 0.0008 ns | 0.0025 ns | 0.0021 ns | 0.0000 ns | - | - |
| IsNotNullEmptyOrWhitespace | 1.1509 ns | 0.0253 ns | 0.0236 ns | 1.1414 ns | - | - |
| Any | 17.0819 ns | 0.3264 ns | 0.3053 ns | 16.9262 ns | 0.0025 | 32 B |
| IsNotEmpty | 0.0011 ns | 0.0047 ns | 0.0042 ns | 0.0000 ns | - | - |

Answer (score -1):

The better option and more elegant is

```
bool notEmpty2 = s.Length > 0
```

This is because it is impossible to have a string less than 0 length

Comment: The logic here eludes me.

Comment: If it's impossible to have less than 0, wouldn't one prefer `!= 0`? Otherwise the check is logically more expensive.